# Any ways to create count column like mysql "COUNT(*) as counted" Column with d7's db_select()?

Tags: 7, forms, database

hello everybody i have to make tableselect form with some extra fields. To make table sortable I have to show which DB fields is used for the column in header:

```
$header = array(
    'uid' => array('data' => t('UID'), 'field' => 'u.uid'),
    'name' => array('data' => t('Name'), 'field' => 'u.name'),
    'mail'=>array('data' => t('Mail'), 'field' => 'u.mail'),
    'last_access' => array('data' => t('Last Access'), 'field' => 'u.access'),
    'login_count' => array('data' => t('Login Count'),'field'=>'a.count_logins'),
    'join_date'=>array('data' => t('Join Date'), ),
    'post_count'=>array('data' => t('Posts Count'),),
    'comment_count'=> array('data' => t('Comment Count'),)
  );
```

then I created a query for this:

```
$query = db_select('users','u');
  $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort');
  $query->leftJoin(db_select('mycustom_report','r')->fields('r',array('count(*)    AS  count_logins','uid'))->groupBy('uid'),'a','a.uid=u.uid');
  $uids = $query
    ->fields('u',array('uid','name','mail','access'))->fields('a',array('count_logins'))->where('u.uid!=0')
    ->limit(50)
    ->orderByHeader($header)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```

this query gives me this error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'r.countAScount_logins'
```

any ways to create count field with db_select method in drupal? db_query() seems does not support ->orderByHeader() method

my full query which works fine looks like:

```
select u.uid,u.created,u.name,u.mail,u.access,counted_login,counted_post,counted_comment 
  from users as u 
          left join (select r.uid, count(*) as counted_login  from mycustom_report as r group by r.uid ) as d on u.uid = d.uid 
          left join (select r.uid, count(*) as counted_post from node as r group by r.uid ) as p on p.uid = u.uid
          left join (select r.uid, count(*) as counted_comment from comment as r group by r.uid ) as c on c.uid = u.uid;
```

Comment: to_string rendered this SELECT u.uid AS uid, u.name AS name, u.mail AS mail, u.access AS access, a.count_logins AS count_logins FROM {users} u LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT r.countAScount_logins AS countAScount_logins, r.uid AS uid FROM {mycustom_report} r GROUP BY uid) a ON a.uid=u.uid WHERE (u.uid!=0) ORDER BY u.uid ASC

Answer (score 2):

This error simply means that column does not exist in your database which means u have to write addExpression() method for solving these problem as follows and even you have not joined the table properly use your query as below

```
$query = db_select('users','u');
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort');
$query->leftJoin('mycustom_report','r','r.uid=u.uid');
$query->fields('r');
$query->fields('u');
$query->addExpression('COUNT(uid)', 'uid_count');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

this will surely removes your error the main issue with your query is that you are combining the db_query syntax with db_select

Answer (score 1):

Here is the D7 approach to a count function.  It will also rewrite it for you so you can have a single function/query and return the count or the actual query.

```
function example($count=FALSE) {
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition('n.title', $title, '=');

  if($count) return $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
  // Or you can just return the results.
  return $query->execute();
}
```